# Wordpress login programmatically with user name/cookies

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, authentication

I am taking user information from a cookie. And, after the user come at my WordPress site, I want to login it automatically. I tried a lot of solution. But they are not working. Please tell me everything with detail. I can print "SUCCESS" on the console, but it doesn't work. This user is an administrator, but if I click https://www.example.com/wp-admin, Wordpress wants my credentials again.
That is my code (it is in the index.php file)

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['xxxx'])) {
    $user_email = $_COOKIE['xxxxx'];
    $decrypted = my_decryption($user_email);   //it is encrypted data, and I decrypt it.

    define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

    /** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
    require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );

    if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        $username = $decrypted;
        $user = get_user_by('login', $username );
        clean_user_cache($user->ID);
        wp_clear_auth_cookie();
        wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true, false);
        update_user_caches($user);
    }
    if ( is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        echo ("
        <script>
            console.log('SUCCESSS')
        </script>
        ");
    } 
}
else {
    echo "You are not authenticated for seeing this page!";
}
```

Please help me! I am stuck with that for 7 days. (I know security issues, please just tell me how it works)

Comment: Print out the values of various variables throughout and figure out where it's going wrong. Make sure `$user->ID` is what you expect, for example.

Comment: @ceejayoz actually all variables are working. But I cannot initialize a session for the current user. I installed a plugin logs user login. This plugins shows me user can log in successfully. it is odd :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should write your code to functions.php file. Also, you should put your codes in pieces for invoke it. I write code again but I think there are some parts to fix.

```
add_action( 'init', 'setting_my_first_cookie' );

function setting_my_first_cookie() {

if(isset($_COOKIE['xxx'])) {
    $user_email = $_COOKIE['xxx'];
    $decrypted = simple_decrypt($user_email);

if( !email_exists( $decrypted )){
    wp_create_user( $decrypted, $user_email . $user_email , $decrypted );
}
if(!is_user_logged_in()){
    $username = $decrypted;
    $user = get_user_by('login', $username );

    clean_user_cache($user->ID);
    wp_clear_auth_cookie();
    wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true, false);
    update_user_caches($user);

        echo ("
        <script>
            console.log('".  wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true, false) ."')
        </script>
        ");
        }
    }
    else {
        return "You are not authenticated for seeing this page!";
    }
}
```